# Uncaught TypeError: this.firstname is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm studying knockout js and happened error
whats is the problem??

```html
<span data-bind="text: fullname"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');

  this.fullname = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
  },this);
}

// <!-- ko.applyBindings(viewModel); -->
var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

when I call this,

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.firstname is not a function
```

happen...
what is wrong?

Comment: look at capitalization... `this.firstName = ...` and `return this.firstname() + ...`. This issue also exists with your `this.lastName`/`this.lastname` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At

```
return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
```

You did not capitalize the "n" in `firstname` and `lastname`. So try something like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');

  this.fullname = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  },this);
}

// <!-- ko.applyBindings(viewModel); -->
var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```